# How can I show div when onbeforeunload

Tags: jquery

I have a custom alert message made from div. How can I fade In the div when the page is want to reload or close ? Any other better suggestion to do that? Thanks

```js
   window.onbeforeunload = function() {
         $(".alert").fadeIn();
      }
```

```css
.alert{
  height:80px;
  width:200px;
  padding:10px;
  text-align:center;
  border:1px solid #000;
  display:none;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert">Are you sure ?</div>
```

Comment: You cannot stop the unload event behaviour without prompting a message from `onbeforeunload` event, meaning returning string from it. So basically, what you are trying to do cannot be done (in a cross browser way)

Comment: @A.Wolff any other way can do this ?

Comment: This is the way it should be done, returning string from `onbeforeunload` event: http://jsfiddle.net/dag8xrvd/  Now, AFAIK, Firefox doesn't allow any custom message (not sure about current version)

Comment: @A.Wolff but I want my own alert style

Comment: As i said and as i'm aware of, this is **not possible**! If you know for example an online website showing this behaviour, feel free to share it

Comment: @A.Wolff one question , if I want to do this when a button is click? How?

Comment: @A.Wolff is okay i know how to do ~ thanks